# How to combine two regex's?

Tags: node.js, regex, jsonschema

I need to validate string to be alphanumeric and also avoid of SQL expressions inside it.

For completing this validation using `jsonschema` library, I built those two regex's -

First:

```
"([0-9]\\s*[0-9])"
```

Second:

```
"(^[insert|INSERT|into|INTO|delete|Delete|update|UPDATE|set|SET|where|WHERE|between|BETWEEN|like|LIKE|group by|GROUP BY|order by|ORDER BY|drop|DROP|truncate|TRUNCATE|create|CREATE|table|TABLE|join|JOIN|count|COUNT|avg|AVG|sum|SUM|null|NULL|(|)|{|}|[|]|,|.|;|])"
```

How can I add 'AND' operator to combine them?

Comment: Just run the string through 2 regexes. This example you provided won't combine because the 2nd regex begins with the '^' start character.

Comment: I need to have one expression to handle it, im using 'jsonshema'

Comment: there is no limit. Only the limit you set yourself

Comment: what do you mean no limit? how can I add more patterns? a list? another pattern attribute?

Comment: The syntax for the second pattern is not correct, it should be a group instead of a character class `(insert|INSERT|into|INTO|delete|Delete|update|UPDATE|set|SET|where|WHERE|between|BETWEEN|like|LIKE|group by|GROUP BY|order by|ORDER BY|drop|DROP|truncate|TRUNCATE|create|CREATE|table|TABLE|join|JOIN|count|COUNT|avg|AVG|sum|SUM|null|NULL|[|{},.;])` The first pattern matches 2 digits with optional spaces in between. What exacly are you trying to match? Can you update your question with some clear examples?

Comment: "i need to have one expression" is wrong. There is no limit

Comment: @SteveTomlin can you please share an example how to use several patterns ?

Comment: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/3561

Answer (score 3):

You combine the two conditions just like you combine any other two conditions in json schema - with the `allOf` keyword.

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#allof

Comment: I actually tried to make it, but its working partially - I have a test per each one of the fields, and it's working fine, then the other test case for no errors showing me errors for some reason